# WPF MediaElement briefly stutters when trying to buffer/preload next video

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

Am trying to write a program that can play a series of video files in a smooth manner as if it were just one long video. Previous questions on the topic I found online recommended preloading/buffering next video and then switching over only once the new video is ready. I've written a test program doing just that.

The switching between current player / next player with the buffered video works fine, but there is a brief stutter in the playback (only a fraction of a second, but very noticeable) when I assign the new MediaElement.Source / open the next file.

Any idea on how to solve this? do I need to split off a thread with Task.Run()? (but am afraid that will create ownership conflicts with the UI thread...). Is this just a performance limitation with MediaElement and are there workarounds / alternatives? would this https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement work better for instance?

the really crazy thing btw. is that i even tried to open 2 different windows, with second window on its own thread, but the first video *still* stutters when the second window is loading its file.

thanks!

I have written the simple test program below.

Window has 3 superimposed MediaElements, Player1/Player2/Player3. Player1 is always playing even when hidden (i need that for other reasons that are not relevant to current problem). Two of the players are hidden at all times (opacity = 0) and I preload the next video into a hidden player while another one is visible and playing.

As said above, the problem is that the playback in the visible player stutters briefly when the hidden player loads the next file.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
            <MediaElement x:Name="Player1" MediaOpened="P1MediaOpened" Stretch="UniformToFill" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />
            <MediaElement x:Name="Player2" Stretch="UniformToFill" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />
            <MediaElement x:Name="Player3" Stretch="UniformToFill" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />
        </Grid>
</Window>type here
```

cs file:

```
namespace Test_App
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Player2.Opacity = 0.0;
            Player3.Opacity = 0.0;
            Player2.Volume = 0.0;
            Player3.Volume = 0.0;
            Player1.Source = new Uri("I:BaseVideo.mp4");
            Player1.Play();

            Loaded += LoadNextVideos;
        }

        private async void LoadNextVideos(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Player2.Source = new Uri("002.mp4");
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            
            Player2.Play();
            Player2.Opacity = 1.0;
            Player1.Opacity = 0.0;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Player3.Source = new Uri("003.mp4");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Player3.Play();
            Player3.Opacity = 1.0;
            Player2.Opacity = 0.0;
            Player2.Pause();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Player2.Source = new Uri("004.mp4");
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            Player2.Play();
            Player2.Opacity = 1.0;
            Player3.Opacity = 0.0;
            Player3.Pause();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Player3.Source = new Uri("005.mp4");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Player3.Play();
            Player3.Opacity = 1.0;
            Player2.Opacity = 0.0;
            Player2.Pause();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Player2.Source = new Uri("006.mp4");
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in the end I gave up on trying to solve this with wpf mediaelement and switched to using FMME, which turns out to not have the stuttering issue. I'll close this question.

Comment: Can you share you implementation on FFME?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're trying to show two MediaElement on top of one another. please try to set the Visibility to Visibility.Collapsed and set to Visibility.Visible instead of Opacity.

Comment: thank you. unfortunately it's the exact same stutter behavior (which btw also happens if I use just a single MediaElement, and also happens if I try using MediaPlayer rather than MediaElement). At this point I don't think it's fixable with MediaElement and I'll try using FMME or WPF-Mediakit and see if they behave better. Will report back here.